# How to open VSD files in OSX using Google drive?

Tags: networking

Networking administrator from another enterprise who use Juniper router's sent me a VSD file (I use OSX for programming objective-C, Swift, Qt/C++, BASH, terminal to connect my other linux boxes for BASH,Lua,Python and only on my OSX GUI i use Google chrome with Google drive all my files)

How do i open the VSD File on my Google drive? Tried `Lucidchart` failed

[image]

Comment: Note to people considering closing this question as off-topic, being about an application: I consider it on topic as a question about a tool used by network professionals.

Comment: @JFL, while Visio may be a tool commonly used by network engineers, Visio support would be found on [su], and Visio for OSX may be found on [apple.se], but the question is really asking for an off-topic product or resource recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSD files are [Microsoft Visio](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) files (commonly used for Network Diagrams among other things).

You have two ways to open it on OSX that I am aware of:

- Use a Windows Virtual Machine and install either Microsoft Viso (payed) or the [free Visio Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51188)
- Install the native OSX program [Omnigraffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniGraffle) (payed - trial available)

There may be other programs able to open Visio files though.

Comment: It appears there are vsd-to-pdf converters online which might help too.

Comment: @jonathanjo good to know, you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've no experience of them, but searching for "vsd file converter online" and "vsd to svg" yields a few promising results including

- https://cloudconvert.com/vsd-to-svg
- https://www.zamzar.com/convert/vsd-to-pdf/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/vsd2svg/

Do please comment if any of these help with your specific file.